# trying to kill a codeigniter session using another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Working on a project based in CodeIgniter.

In my user menu, I use the code

```
    <?php   if (isset($username))
        echo '<li class="right" style="float: right;"><a href="'.site_url().'logout/">Logout</a></li>
        '; ?>
```

which shows causes a logout button to appear if the username variable is set.

This takes them to the logout.php controller, which reads as follows:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Logout extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     */
    public function index() {
        if (isset($username)) {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(site_url() . 'login/'); exit();
        }

    }
}

/* End of file login.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/logout.php */
```

The problem is currently that when I click the logout button, the logout controller loads, and stays a blank page. It does not redirect back to the login page.

I also tried as

```
redirect(site_url()); exit();
```

EDIT:

This isn't exactly the fix I had in mind, but it is functional: 
to the login.php controller, I added to the index function the lines:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        $logout = $this->input->post("logout");
        if ($logout == 'logout') 
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }
```

Then, I changed my userbar:

```
<?php   if (isset($username))
        echo '<form id="logout" action="'.site_url().'login/" method="post">
        <input id="logout" name="logout" type="hidden" value="logout"/>
        <input id="l_submit" name="L_submit" type="submit" value="logout" />
            </form>

        '; ?>
```

OK, so it IS functional that way, but I didn't want a button; I wanted it it to match my CSS as a

item.

Comment: why don't you just try loading your main view?

Comment: do you mean by adding a line `$this->load->view('login', $BB_DATA);` to my Logout controller? because I tried that, and that did not work.

Comment: Edits coming, I found something which DID work, but I don't like it

Comment: does the action in the form and the anchor rendered in the same destination? `logout`?